# Problems publishing on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to publish a ASP.NET web application to my server but Visual Studio shows me this dialog:

[image]

There is no more info on the output.

Anyone knows about this problem?

Comment: Do you have an English translation?

Comment: The dialog box says _"An exception occurred while establishing connectionId"_.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, try publishing to the File System to check that there is nothing wrong with the build. Repeat with the option Web Deploy Package.

After that, check the settings for either FTP or Web Deploy. For FTP you have the option to validate the connection. For Web Deploy, there can be a number of connections string to be set. If possible, try to check each one separately.

Comment: I can´t publish at all. The dialog shows when yo click on contextual menu "Publish" who shows the other window with the select "File" "Web" ...